# javascriptを用いてPC上の他のウインドウを検知することはできますか？

Tags: javascript, browser

私はWebサイトを作っているのですが、ユーザーが別のタブでどのサイトを見ているのか、PC上で別のソフトウェアを開いているかどうかを検知することは可能ですか？
タイトルではjavascriptと書いていますが、別にjavascript以外の手段でも構いません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

単なるウェブサイトにおいてブラウザ上で無制限にこれができてしまうとユーザーのプライバシー的にまずいです。基本的にはできないものと考えて問題ないと思われます。

ただし「同じブラウザの他のタブで自分と同じページが開かれているか」に限定すれば、localStorage の仕組みを使うなどして検知することは[可能です](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23690666/5989200)。個人的にはユーザーの自由を奪っているようであまりオススメしたくありませんが……。

また、拡張機能を使ってウェブサイト外の仕組みで実現することは可能です。この場合ブラウザについている機能を使うことになります（例：[`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)）。一般的なブラウザでは実行前にユーザーに権限の許可を問う形になっているはずです。

Comment: 「別のタブで何のサイトを見ているか」ではなく、「別のタブを開いているか否か」を検知するのも難しいですか？

Comment: 多分無理だと思いますが、仮に可能だったとしても「他の種類のブラウザを開く」「別のデバイスでブラウザを開く」など可能なので Yoka さんがなさりたいことができないのではないだろうかと考えています。別のタブやウィンドウが開いていることを検知して何をなさりたいのでしょうか？

Comment: WEB上で簡単な質問に答えるシステムをWeb開発の練習がてら個人的に作っていたのですが、その際にカンニングの検知をjsで出来ないものかと考えていたのです。

Comment: では既に述べたようにブラウザの機能では限界がありますね。他の方向で解決を考えるのが良いと思います。

Comment: @Yoka さん> 横から失礼します。回答者が自身のパソコンを用いて質問へ回答する場合には、既に nekketsuuu さんがおっしゃっているように、別のデバイスや紙資料を使用したカンニングも考えられ、本質的なカンニングへの対策は困難なため、 Web カメラなどを通して監督者を設ける、あらかじめ資料の持ち込みが可能という条件で作問する、などが現実的な妥協点だと思います。 
/ 
「不完全でも良いからそういう仕組みを作ってみたい」ということであれば、 [Web ページがフォーカスを失ったことを検知](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event)すれば、試験中に解答以外の行為をしていると見なせる場合があります。

Comment: @supa さん> フォーカスが外れただけでは不正行為と判断することはできませんが、不正行為をしているかどうかの参考にすることはできますね。ありがとうございます。